# Secret origin of the dude = butthair meme

Tags: meaning, etymology, internet

My daughter came back from Catechism today with an interesting spiritual fact.  Apparently she was told that a dude is another name for butt hair.

It's entry 17 or so on urban dictionary, dated 2006 and searching the internets I see some old stuff from the early aughts referencing a collective conscience that remembers being taught that a dude was an elephants butt hair, or an ingrown one at least.

Is there anything in print in pre-internet days or even a half remembered joke that corroborates this fact, or is it pure mimetical nonsense?

Comment: Fer sure, man. Even before the Net, there was the Dude. Even when the Net is gone, still the Dude abides.

Comment: Yeah, well, that's just like... your opinion, man.

Comment: Dude: (slang) : (Noun) .An infected hair on an elephant's butt.http://www.definition-of.com/dude. Actually it appears there is no reliable source for the origin of this use of *dude*.

Comment: @Josh61 - yeah, but like, what language is that dude, dude? Swahili?

Comment: @LittleEva - dunno :).

Comment: @Josh61 - wanna bet it's not English?

Comment: @LittleEva - This is not an infected hair. It is a regular hair on an elephants butt - in the Bangladesh language. Not english, (Wikipedia)

Comment: oops, @Josh61, my bad. I was assuming Africa.

Comment: This reminds me of when, growing up on a farm, my friends and I would try to beguile newcomers by teaching them the 'proper' vernacular: i.e. a *dude* was a pimple on a horse's butt and a *dudette* a pimple on a horse's, uh, member. Of course, no one ever believed us, nor did we ever think there was any truth to it. Interesting to learn that there actually was.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is absolutely no evidence, anywhere, to support this stupid theory.

Comment: It's just "nonsense". I found [this post](http://www.gaiaonline.com/forum/the-gd/someone-told-me-that-a-camel-s-foreskin-is-called-a-dude/t.16861001/) dated 19 Aug 2006 titled *Someone told me that a camel's foreskin is called a dude!*, where someone else claims that the elephant's butt version appears on Wikipedia (but that was probably just vandalism; I doubt it's still there now).

Comment: Sort of relevant, if you want to learn about what people seriously think is the origin of "dude": [Etymology of “dude” and progression in language](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24009/etymology-of-dude-and-progression-in-language)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an urban legend.

Comment: And this is the type of question that needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

In grade school, it was common knowledge that dude meant 'A hair on an elephant's butt.'  Grade school was the late 80s for me, in the American midwest.  Later on in life I heard this repeated to me by someone that grew up on the east coast.