# Female equivalent of "fellow"

Tags: single-word-requests, analogy

If *sistren* is the female equivalent of *brethren*, what is the female equivalent of *fellow*?  Words usually paired are: *guy/gal*; *man/woman*; *boy/girl*; *lad/lass*; *brethren/sistren*; *fraternity/sorority*; but I have seen nothing for *fellow*.

Comment: Related: [What is a feminine version of 'guys'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19074/what-is-a-feminine-version-of-guys)

Comment: @Cerberus ['Dolls'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guys_and_Dolls)!

Comment: @ESultanik: Yeah, Mitch mentions that one as well in his question about *guys*, and it would be a fun word to use once in a while in a suitable group.

Answer (score 9):

According to [Etymology Online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fellow), fellow has been:

> Used familiarly since mid-15c. for
>   "man, male person," but not
>   etymologically masculine.

It would be perfectly acceptable to call a woman a fellow traveler, for instance.

A similarly toned word for a woman, but not related to fellow, might be simply lady, or woman, as in, "my dear lady...".

Comment: Can the same be said about "fellas", to replace something like `Hello ladies and gentlemen` - `Hello fellas` ?

Comment: @bigp Although I assume "fellas" is a slang variant of "fellows" and maintains the same etymological neutrality, my intuition is that the majority of English speakers would interpret "fellas" as masculine.

Answer (score 2):

*Fellow* in the context of an organization or group is gender neutral. *Girl, woman* or *gal* otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could conceivably get away with using "fellow" for a woman.  ("For she's a jolly good fellow!", although that may be limited to the context of the song.)  If you want a word with the same sort of archaic feel as fellow, "chapess" might do the job, although it's both colloquial, and a neologism, as was as being more obviously paired with "chap".

Answer (score 1):

To treat only a special case, *"a fellow of [some organization]"* seems to be treated as fully gender neutral.

*"She is a APS Fellow"* is fine and simply carries the respect that comes with the position.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is ["sheila"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sheila)

N.B., this answer was edited.

Comment: Not the best choice because *lass* is a regional word and in a different social register.  And *lassie* could be taken as quite rude.  And it only applies to young women.

Comment: And it reminds me of a dog :D

Comment: Hahaha! At Alenanno, the way words can develop meanings!

Comment: @Alenanno - "Woof, woof!" "What's that you say, Lassie?  The English language has fallen down a hole?"  "Woof, woof, woof!"  "And both its legs are broken?"  "Woof, woof!"  "Good girl, Lassie!  Let's go get it!"

Comment: It's worth leaving some indication that you've so thoroughly edited an answer just so that those coming along later are not confused by comments that seem to have no relation to the answer.

Comment: Dude, your edit made it a whole different answer! Which are you offering, __lassie__ or __sheila__?

Comment: _Sheila_ would seem specifically Australian English to my [British] ears.

Comment: @z7sgѪ I have come to understand lass[ie] to be quite neutral from my short experience living in Scotland. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Either ***girl*** or ***gal***, depending on age of the subject and the context, would carry about the same air of casualness as *fellow*.

> You son is a cute little fellow.
> Your daughter is a cute little gal.
>
> Who's that fellow over there? And who's the girl with him?

If she is stuck in the 1950's and calling her boyfriend her *fellow*, those words would work for what he would call *her*, too. If she is a fellow in the collegiate sense, she is of course a *fellow*.

Sorry, but I can't come up with a unique form of *fellow* that is not already paired with one of the others. I wonder if it's a holdover from the era when women were treated with more respect (in polite society, and in public, at least), and so there's a dearth of casual yet respectable words for women from that time. (I may be wrong about the use of *fellow* elsewhere, but in general I only hear older people using the word).

Answer (score 0):

I have heard the expression "every fellow needs a [filly](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/filly)". It's originally used to refer to a female horse but has a less common informal meaning that's comparable to fellow.

Comment: I would not recommend using "filly" as a counterpart to fellow.  Many women consider this derogative in a way that's related to "cow", "bitch", etc (although not quite as bad, it still comes over as condescending).

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of that connotation. I've never used the word myself. I usually end up rephrasing the sentence to avoid fellow/chap.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard folks from a couple of generations back change the lyrics of the song *for he's a jolly good fellow* when singing it to a female (any age) to *for she's a jolly good lassie*

Based on that, *lass* or more informal *lassie* would be contenders.

Comment: I've more often heard "For she's a jolly good fellow".