# Why do guys call each other “man”?

Tags: etymology, terminology, hailnames

Just curious. Why do a lot of guys call each other “man”? What’s the origin of that term? EXAMPLE: “Hey, man. What’s up?”

Comment: Because they don't remember each other's names.

Comment: When I started calling people 'man', it was for exactly that reason, due to marijuana.

Comment: Of related interest: *[How do you say “Come on, man” to a woman?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/435111)*, *[Is there a word for colloquial forms of address?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334424)*, and *[What is a feminine version of 'guys'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19074)* among many others.

Comment: There's nothing new about addressing another person familiarly as _man, woman, boy, girl_ or _child_. It can add emphasis or be an affectionate form of address.

Answer (score 1):

***[Man](https://www.etymonline.com/word/man)***:

> as a word of familiar address, originally often implying impatience, c. 1400; hence probably its use as an interjection if surprise or emphasis, since Middle English but especially popular from early 20 c.

(Etymonline)