# How to address one male and one female in an informal email?

Tags: formality, email

In an inter-company (informal) email, when the addressees are one male and one female, I usually use `Hi Guys`. However, `guy` has a distinct male flavour.
Could you suggest a more gender-neutral addressing for the above?

Comment: I think most people in the corporate world would consider "guys" to be non-gender specific these days.

Comment: Also relevant:[What is a feminine version of guys](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19074/what-is-a-feminine-version-of-guys)

Comment: I use  **folks** as an informal, gender-neutral term for more than one person.

Comment: Which country are you in? What is preferable may vary between different English-speaking countries.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with simply using *Hi.*

Comment: @TrevorD, I currently work in British Columbia, Canada.

Comment: I won't attempt to answer your Q. then, as I am born & bred British!  My brother lives in BC, and he comes up with expressions that I would never use!

Answer (score 1):

If it's one specific male and one specific female, just address them by name: "Hi Adam and Betty".

If the context is informal, "hi everyone" or "hi all" would work.

Comment: I feel that all/everyone is for _crowds,_ namely for more than a couple.